# Can I define attributes with non-unique names but with different NameFormats?

Tags: shibboleth

I am running a Shibboleth SP (version 2.4.3) and my attribute-map.xml includes the default mapping for "mail"

```
<!-- email -->
<Attribute name="urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:mail" id="mail"/>
<Attribute name="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3" id="mail"/>
```

A client is using a non-Shibboleth IdP, and they don't have the ability to define the NameFormat as anything other than `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic`.
According to the Shibboleth wiki if an IdP uses a NameFormat other than `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri` or `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified` then I have to define the NameFormat in my own attribute-map.xml.

Can/should I add a third Attribute node with an identical name but with the "basic" nameFormat defined? I don't want to disrupt my existing integrations with clients who are doing things the standard Shibboleth way.

```
<!-- email -->
<Attribute name="urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:mail" id="mail"/>
<Attribute name="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3" id="mail"/>
<Attribute name="urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:mail" id="mail" nameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any attribute in attribute map file, but you have to make sure idP sends it before using it. 
And it won't affect on any existing connection.